# Prevent a value from being entered if it's a prefix of another value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, unique-constraint

How could I prevent a value from being entered that is a prefix of another value in the same column? For example, if `MyTable.NumberPrefix` already contains `abc` then `ab` can't be added.

My first attempt (below) was to use an indexed view. But a unique index cannot be created on a view that uses a derived table (and I can't figure out how to write the view without it).

```
create view MyTable
with schemabinding
as
select
  left(a.NumberPrefix, b.Length) as CommonPrefix
from 
  dbo.MyTable a
  cross join
  (
    select distinct
      len(NumberPrefix) as Length
    from
      dbo.MyTable
  ) b

create unique clustered index MyIndex on MyTable (CommonPrefix) --ERROR
```

Some test data:

```
insert MyTable (NumberPrefix) values ('abc')  -- OK
insert MyTable (NumberPrefix) values ('ab')   -- Error
insert MyTable (NumberPrefix) values ('a')    -- Error
insert MyTable (NumberPrefix) values ('abd')  -- OK
insert MyTable (NumberPrefix) values ('abcd') -- Error
```

Comment: In the above example do you want to prevent "a" from being added?

Comment: Yes, anything that is a prefix of another value.

Comment: 'abcd' is not a prefix of the others, why error?

Comment: Because `abc` is already there, and is a prefix of `abcd`.

Comment: Can't you join on an auxiliary numbers table rather than the derived table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `check constraint` with `user defined function`:

```
create function fnPrefix(@prefix varchar(100))
returns bit
as
begin
    if (select count(*) from MyTable 
        where MyColumn like @prefix + '%' or @prefix like MyColumn + '%') > 1
        return 0

    return 1
end
```

Then add constraint:

```
alter table MyTable
add constraint  chkPrefix check(dbo.fnPrefix(MyColumn) = 1)
```

Comment: This works (prevents adding) `ab` if `abc` exists, but it doesn't work if `ab` is there first and you insert `abc`.

Comment: One use case doesn't preclude another.